# How to stuff a result of a query into a variable and use it another query in a logic app

Tags: azure, azure-logic-apps

I haven't used logic apps a lot, my boss is having trouble stuffing the results of one query into a variable and then using that variable in another query.

Basically, all he wants to do is get a list of of Id's returned from the first query and use that list in the second.

Here is a picture of what his logic app looks like:
[image]

You can see at the end of the second query he wants to check if the id is in the list or not. He's out for the day and I'm not sure if that variable is even receiving the list of id's successfully, but is there anything from the picture that you can tell that needs to be corrected? Or any suggestions that he could try, to achieve what he's trying to achieve?

Answer (score 1):

According to the image, no data is getting stored into the variable AppId. While in the query you can just directly use `c.EntityId`. Below query to check if c.id is present in c.EntityId.

```
SELECT c.Vechicle.GrossVechicleWeight as GVW, c.EntityId as ApplicationId FROM c where c.RiskTypeId = 1 and c.Discriminator = 'RiskEntity' and c.EntityTypeId = 4500 and c.id in (c.EntityId)
```

Consider if you are trying to store c.Entity into AppId variable then you can Query `SELECT c.EntityId FROM c` and then store the result into the variable using `Append to array variable` action by extracting only c.EntityId using `Parse JSON`.

Here is my logic app

[image]

[image]

**RESULT:**

[image]

Comment: I appreciate the answer! My next question, is it possible to use that variable in another query? For example in my picture above, you can see where he wants to check if id is in the array